# How to play intro before video? Video.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, video.js

Is it possible to play an intro before a video and then the video?

The user clicks the play button, the intro of the page plays and, once finished, then the actual video. Intro is a typical `.mp4` file.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for the `ended` event and swap out the `src`:

```js
const video = document.querySelector('video');

video.addEventListener('ended', () => {
  video.setAttribute('src', 'https://node-images-test.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/Pexels+Videos+2292093.mp4')
})
```

```css
video {
  width: 500px
}
```

```html
<video src="https://node-images-test.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/pointing_grey.mp4" controls></video>
```